# Settings или файл

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать ваши мнения по поводу того, где хранить данные, которые пользователь может изменять (например, цвет фона). В файле или как поля Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле Settings хранятся также в файле (правда хранится он в "ж"), используя механизм сериализации, только это происходит "не гласно" (никогда не задумывался над возможностью указать место хранения данной информации - возможно это реально). Мне почему-то сложно дать конкретные рекомендации, что лучше применять, хотя я их использовал много раз. Я все таки предпочитаю сам управлять механизмом сохранения настроек для приложения: в таком подходе вы всегда знаете ГДЕ искать файл с сохраненной информацией, а также можете поставлять ваше приложение вместе с данным файлом. К тому же это позволит пользователям редактировать данные настройки "руками", в случае xml сериализации. В случае с Settings (несмотря на то, что вы можете задать значения по умолчанию) бывают ситуации, когда у пользователей приложения появляются "непонятки" и лишние вопросы, поэтому я предпочитаю избегать Settings. К тому же, если вы знакомы с механизмом сериализации, реализовать сохранение настроек довольно просто, прозрачно и не требует множества затрат и времени.